# woocommerce products by category repeated first 10 products on each page so how to display all product?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I created custom code for woocommerce products show as per selected category, first 10 product display as per the category  but on the second page of pagination same 10 products are displayed, also at all page the same product are display, when products are order by rand then result is correct but i want result by title so please give me the solution for that my code is as below.

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php $cat_slug=get_queried_object()->slug; ?>
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => $cat_slug, 'orderby' => 'title' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

        <li class="product_cust ">   
            <div class="woo_100">
                <div id="woo_c">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                    <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <div class="woo_thumb">
                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div id="woo_d">

                    <div class="woo_desc">
                        <div class="nil_desc">
                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop1->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop1->post->post_title ? $loop1->post->post_title : $loop1->post->ID); ?>">
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </a>
                            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span><br>
                        </div>


                        <div class="nil_cart"><?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop1->post, $product ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                                              
                </div>  
            </div> 
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>         
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not passed any variable to paginate it.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',  'product_cat' => $cat_slug, 'orderby' => 'title', 'paged'=>$paged);
```

Also after your loop use nav.php to get pagination control links.